# How to achieve landscape and pixel ration media query with sass-breakpoint

Tags: sass, media-queries, susy-compass, susy, breakpoint-sass

How to achieve this media query with sass breakpoint? ...

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape)
```

I've tried this, but it affects the desktop version as well ...

```
$mobileLandscape: screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape);

@include breakpoint($mobileLandscape) {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how to achieve what you want with breakpoint sass (breakpoint-sass bower package).
I have tried it in chrome (and simulate device with web developper tools) and it works.

```
// With third-party tool
// Breakpoint https://github.com/at-import/breakpoint
// You can find installation instructions here https://github.com/at-import/breakpoint/wiki/Installation
$mobile-landscape-breakpoint: 'only screen' 375px 667px, (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio 2), (orientation landscape);

body {
    @include breakpoint($mobile-landscape-breakpoint) {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

If breakpoint seems too complicated, You can achieve this with your own code.
For example :

```
// With Variable
$mobileLandscape: "only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)";

@media #{$mobileLandscape} {
    body {
        color: red;
    }
}

// With Mixin
@mixin mq($breakpoint){
    @if $breakpoint == "mobile-landscape"{
        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape){
            @content;
        }
    }
}

body{
    @include mq("mobile-landscape"){
        color: green;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work, the first one using breakpoint doesn't target the landscape for mobile only, it targets every mobile and tablet.

The second solution doesn't compile using gulp-sass.

But when using the media query as is it works fine, I just want to use a shortcut for this media query, that's it, so I'm asking how to use breakpoint to achieve this shortcut.

Comment: The mixin solution seems to work by the way, but I'm just scratching my head, how to do it with breakpoint?
There must be away.